# undefined method `order' for []:Array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, undefined

I have the following code where I load the activities for the user based on whether or not they are an admin.  Users can only see their own activity feed, whereas admins can see the entire stream.  This is a precursor to sharing activity feeds with friends, etc.

```
  def index
    if current_user?
      @incidents = Incident.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id).order("created_at desc")
    else
      @incidents = Incident.all.order("created_at desc")
    end
  end
```

I am getting the above referenced error(`undefined method "order" for []:Array`).  It seems to be the `.order` reference, but I have checked the rails Guides and it seems to be correct syntax.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the `find_by...` to `where`, so:

```
def index
    if current_user?
      @incidents = Incident.where(user_id: current_user.id).order("created_at desc")
    else
      @incidents = Incident.all.order("created_at desc")
    end
  end
```

should work :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `#index` action method can be simplified and optimized (by replacement `find_all_by` with `where`) to:

```
 def index
   clause = current_user? && Incident.where(user_id: current_user.id) || Incident
   @incidents = clause.order("created_at desc")
 end
```

Comment: An elegant solution, but a little complex for a beginner.

Comment: @br3nt what did you make the changes for?

Comment: @br3nt for me it has excessive syntax and is not really needed in the language...